# How to create a view to display all the files in an extension?

Tags: extension

I want to create a view to show all the created templates and provide the user option to edit and delete the already uploaded file..For example a view like Mailings>>Message Templates.

I have seen to implement this i want to create a tpl file and tpl.php file for it. I don't get how should i implement this in my extension.mean i don't get how to generate a tpl.php file and create route for it.

Hope you understand the question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for civix. To create a page like the mailing templates you could use `civix generate:form`, as described at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-form

If you prefer to create an angular page, you can also use civix to generate the basic code: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/angular/quickstart/#create-an-angular-module

Comment: thank you for your response. can i how should i create a table within the buildquickform method ?

Comment: You assign variables in hook_civicrm_buildForm() using `$this->assign('variable_name', $value);` and then you can display them in a table in the .tpl file, e.g. `<div>something</div><div>{$variable_name}</div>`. Take a look at an existing table like the mailing templates to see what it does. It's technically a page not a form, but they're similar. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386/CRM/Admin/Page/MessageTemplates.php and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386/templates/CRM/Admin/Page/MessageTemplates.tpl

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail answer

Comment: i want to display the templates name as the row of a table. i planned to extract the data from a sql query and send it into the tpl file and print it by using a loop. however i don't get how should i send the sql result to front end?? 
in line 127 of 'https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386b3ba951f856e50e3fab7f7695ffd56ba/templates/CRM/Admin/Page/MessageTemplates.tpl ' they used a $template_row variable. I'm just wondering where did they assign these variable...could you please clarify my doubts ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: $template_row comes from line 87. It's used in looping through the `$rows` array (see https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl). And `$rows` comes from the php file: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386/CRM/Admin/Page/MessageTemplates.php#L273, and that comes from a few lines earlier https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386/CRM/Admin/Page/MessageTemplates.php#L246-L254, which is like SQL but using the [DB framework](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.php). There's a lot to learn just to make a table!

Comment: thank you very much, yeah there are so many things to learn.. i have another confusion here - 'https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386b3ba951f856e50e3fab7f7695ffd56ba/CRM/Admin/Page/MessageTemplates.php#L246-L254' it creates object from CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate();..if i want to create a object from a new table which was created by myself is there any specific class to do it ?

Comment: Look at `civix generate:entity`. It will help create the classes you can use. And see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/database/schema-definition/ for the xml definitions.

Comment: okay . thank you Demerit

Comment: i have another small confusion,from where i can get the action ID and it's corresponding value? ex: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386b3ba951f856e50e3fab7f7695ffd56ba/templates/CRM/Admin/Page/MessageTemplates.tpl#L11 
sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: Do you mean how to find out what the numbers mean? They're defined at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0dcdc386/CRM/Core/Action.php#L28

Comment: yeah yeah.thank you for the quick response :)